# python - move some items on a list to the end

Tags: python, list

I would like to perform the following action most **efficiently** :

Lets say we have this list:

```
items = ['a','c','d','e','f','s'] #items are unique (can be a set, but its a list so items are ordered)
special_items = ['e','a']
```

The result should be to convert `items` to be:

```
items = ['c','d','f','s','e','a'] # e,a now at the end
```

**My current solution is:**

```
items = [item for item in items if item not in special_items] #remove special items
items.extend(special_items) #add them to the end of the list
```

It works fine, but not very efficient i believe.

Comment: What if the items occur more than once?

Comment: Why do you think this is not efficient?

Comment: @thefourtheye as i mentioned in the comment, the items can be a set, so you can assume each item is unique in both lists

Comment: If it's a `set` then it's unordered and so adding something "to the end" makes no sense. Unless you meant `set` in the mathematical sense but they're still actually lists?

Comment: @Ffisegydd thats why i used a list, but you can assume items are unique

Comment: @Tichodroma I really dont know, and have a little knowledge of this issues, that why i asked the question. tnx for the comment

Comment: I think you're doing a premature optimization here; the list comp solution performs just fine.

Comment: So if `e` or `a` aren't in `items`, would they still get "moved" to the end... or only moved to the end if present? (at the moment they're always being added to the end...) - eg: `items = []` will become `['e', 'a']`

Answer (score 3):

<strike>First, you can use `itertools.chain` to join two sequences.</strike> Never mind, see edit below.

**If you don't need the ordering in `items`**, you can subtract one set from another:

```
sitems = set(items)
sspecial = set(special_items)
print(list(itertools.chain(sitems - sspecial, 
                           special_items)))
# ['c', 's', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'a']
```

**If you need the ordering** and `special_items` is large, you can get a boost by converting `special_items` into a set first:

```
sspecial = set(special_items)
list(itertools.chain((x for x in items if x not in sspecial),
                     special_items))
```

**Edit:** turns out `itertools.chain` is not as fast as I thought.

```
%timeit list(itertools.chain((x for x in rdata if x not in rset), rlist))
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 µs per loop

%timeit [x for x in rdata if x not in rset] + rlist
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.2 µs per loop
```

So **do** convert `special_items` into a set, **don't** use `itertools.chain`. (Unless I made a mistake in my testing)

Comment: Note that on my machine, according to timeit, this is about five times slower than the list comprehension solution in the original question, even when making `special_items` a set.

Comment: @TML It's about 400 ns slower on my machine (1.5x slower), but I didn't include the set initialization, and I concatenated special_items after the list comprehension.

Comment: I wasn't trying to criticize your solution so much as help the OP see that he needs to define whether or not he HAS a performance problem before trying to solve it. :)